# SQL 2 Tables join id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I think this is an easy question but i can't find a answer I don't have much time left...
help me please

I have a Table "Anime" with the columns "animeID, Name, ..." and I have the Table "anime_user2" with the columns "anime_userID, ..., users_userID, anime_idAnime(Foreign Key)"

Now I want to get all Names from Table "Anime" that are not in already in the Table "anime_user2" with the ID from the user that is logged in

I tried this but it doesn't work as I wanted :

```
"SELECT Name FROM Anime LEFT JOIN anime_user2 ON idAnime = anime_idAnime WHERE users_userID = $userID AND idAnime != anime_idAnime"
```

There is probably an easier way to solve this but I can't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as

```
select
a.Name
from 
Anime a
left join anime_user2 au 
on au.anime_idAnime = a.animeID
where 
au.anime_idAnime is NULL
```

Here is a **[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dead5/4)** how it works

Comment: Thank you, but this is not all, I have to add something like WHERE users_userID is user

because I only want all Names where users_userid = $userID but if I add an "AND" to the where it's not working again

Comment: but do I simply add it with "AND"? it's not working for me if I do "... AND users_userID != $userID

Comment: NOT NULL confition will return all the data from first table which are not in the 2nd table, so if you need to check or do more filter it must be done on the first table i.e. Anime